# How to check whether a field has been declared or not?

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>
        JS Test
    </title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        if(someObj != null || typeof someObj != 'undefined')
        {
            alert("Success.");
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Failed.");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
```

Why it always return an error message-"someObj is not defined" to me?
I want to put the codes to foot of page to check whether the someObj has been declared or not.

Comment: Why do you think that "someObj" should *not* be null? It's not defined, after all ...

Comment: Also why are you using a deprecated doctype? That HTML isvalid HTML5 but not XHTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it the other way around:

```
    if(typeof someObj != 'undefined' && someObj != null)
    {
        alert("Success.");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Failed.");
    }
```

That is, don't try to actually use `someObj` until after you are sure it has been defined as confirmed with `typeof`.

If in fact the variable isn't defined, when you start your `if` condition with `someObj != null` you get the error "someObj is not defined" because - well, it *isn't* defined.

If you first test it with `typeof` then it won't do the `null` comparison unless it actually is defined.

Comment: I have done as you said, but it still return the error to me. Have you tried that code?

Comment: fortunately, I tried change code to "typeof window.someObj !=null", it's going run and return "Faild." to me. Can you explain that?

Comment: The exactly as in my answer worked for me, and returned "Failed" because `someObj` had not been defined. The `typeof` operator returns a string, so comparing that directly to `null` isn't the right way to use it.

Comment: I remember that ever object be delcared directly in javascript is member of window, so the "someObj" and "window.someObj" should be the same one object. Why "typeof someObj != 'undefined'" will return an error to me, but "typeof window.someObj != 'undefined'" will run as expected?

Answer (score 0):

The way to properly test for the existence of a global variable is like this:

```
if (typeof window.someObj != "undefined" && window.someObj != null) {
    alert("success");
}
```

But, you do realize that there is none of your own custom javascript that could define `someObj` before this piece of code so this test will never find that variable.

Answer (score 0):

If your object is a Jquery object use

`var myObj=$('#myObj');`
`if (myObj.length) {
    alert("Success");
  } else {
    alert("NOt found");
  }`